# Printing textfiles with paragraphs n lines long

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-files, line, paragraph

I have a textfile of a book, and I want to print the file but with paragraphs that are 3 sentences long?

What's the command to use to print this out in the Linux Ubuntu terminal?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The `head` command shows you the entire file content

suppose that textfile exist on Dekstop

you can just type the command:

```
~/Desktop$ head textfile
```

will print the entire content no matter long or short sentences.